# Have kept format of ajaxcalendar control as "dd/mm/yyyy" and want to save in database as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format, 3-tier, calendarextender

I m using ajax calendar control to a textbox, have set its format as `"dd/mm/yyyy" .`

```
  Bapur.Date = txtdate.Text;
```

in data access layer

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bapur.Date;
```

on saving, like above ( where `Date` is a string `Bapur` is object of businesslayer class)
in the database where datatable in database has date as `datetime` format.
m getting an error : `cant convert string to datetime` i dint get error when format was  `"mm/dd/yyyy" .`

Basically, I want users to view date in `dd/mm/yyyy` but on  saving i want it in

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

Have tried a lot but not working.

here is my answer ---- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720162/1445836 -----

Comment: is Bapur.Date string or DateTime?

Comment: obect of business layer class, dont bother with that

Comment: I think bapur is the object and Date is its property right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11720162/1445836 check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got my answer

```
            string old = txtdate.Text;
            string newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(old, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            Bapur.Date = newDate.ToString();
```

Comment: upvoted for constant search and effort in finding answer after asking the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`DateTime.ParseExact("yourDate","formatinWhichYouWant",culture of current string);`

ex:

```
DateTime dt =DateTime.ParseExact("yourDate","formatinWhichYouWant",culture of current string);
```

Comment: yes this is the best way to convert date I have also tried to find some other more precise manner but not able to find any one

Answer (score 0):

```
string myDate = bapur.Text.Split("/");
string dateString = myDate[1] + "/" + myDate[0] + "/" + myDate[2];
```